# Spark-avro Cannot grow BufferHolder because the size is negative - where to look for the cause?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-avro, hortonworks-dataflow

**Environment:**

- Scala 2.11
- Spark 2.4
- Hortownorks SchemaRegistry
- Kafka messages with embedded schema information.

**Context**

As stated above, I am aware of how Hortonworks SchemaRegistry information is embedded in the Kafka message. First 13 bytes of information (1 magic byte + 8 schemaId + 4 schemaVersion) are extracted and cut out of the message after downloading it from Kafka passing only "clean avro" data forward in a column named *valueWithoutEmbeddedInfo*.

I use `com.hortonworks.registries.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClient` to download Schema inside Spark. Then I pass `SchemaVersionInfo.getSchemaText` as a `jsonFormatedSchema`

Schema itself is gigantic, it is a single-line json which is over 5MB however messages are properly deserialized when using Kafka UI to see them.

Script is executed on yarn using `spark-submit`.

**EDIT: How did I get clean avro data**

I used `.withColumn("valueWithoutEmbeddedInfo", expr("substring(value, 14, length(value)-13)")` on the incoming Kafka message

**Problem:**

After downloading messages from Kafka with Avro values, when trying to deserialize them using `from_avro(col(valueWithoutEmbeddedInfo), jsonFormatedSchema)` an error occurs saying `Cannot grow BufferHolder by size -556231 because the size is negative`.

**Question:**

What may be causing this problem and how one should resolve it?

I would appreciate any advice, thank you in advance.

Comment: The error means it couldn't read the data correctly because it's not in an expected format. Please share how you got "clean data"... I suggest taking a look over the unit tests and debug your local data against those examples https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/connector/avro/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/avro/AvroFunctionsSuite.scala

Comment: I have filled the missing part of how did I got clean data in the question

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Hortonworks registry, but 1) You can't stringify your binary Avro data and take its substring, you need to remove data from the actual byte array representation 2) where is it documented that the Schema ID is 8 bytes and version is 4 bytes? And the message ends in 13 bytes that need removed?